# Django: filtering expected content type?

Tags: python, django

Django offers a way to restrict the accepted methods using the `@request_http_method` decorator, so if a particular view can only respond to a GET request we can do:

```
@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def only_get(request):
    pass
```

Otherwise we get a 403 (FORBIDDEN) response.

However, I would also like to accept a `Content-Type` of json. If it's not json it should reject the request as well (I am guessing a 403 response would also be the appropriate one).

Does Django have anything similar to the `require_http_methods` decorator, but for content types? If not, how else could I tackle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that Django has something similar for Content-Type, but you can easily write your Middleware, that would drop requests with wrong Content-Type and then use decorator_from_middleware option.

If you use Django 1.10:

```
class AllowedContentTypes(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        types = kwargs.pop('types') or ['application/json']
        if request.content_type in types:
            response = self.get_response(request)

        else:
            response = HttpResponse() # your response for wrong content type
        return response
```

and apply it to your view like:

```
@decorator_from_middleware_with_args(AllowedContentTypes)(types=['application/json'])
def your_view(request):
    ...
```

Also, you can use Django REST Framework, there you are able to filter Content-Type using Parsers, JSONParser would only allow application/json content-type for requests. It is also would be more useful to implement REST API for you app.

Comment: I didn't do it exactly like that but something similar so I am going to accept this answer :)