# How can I set the accepted content type in django view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-headers

I have some views made in Django. I have realised that the endpoints do not fail with an unsupported media type if I call them with, for instance, binary data instead of json (they only accept json). So, my doubt is: how can I specify the allowed content type of an endpoint in django to make it return a 415 error code? Do I need to implement that logic by hand with a middleware?

Comment: you need to do it by hand.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408715/django-filtering-expected-content-type

Comment: great, thanks! please post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in utility for that.
But you can easily create a middleware for it yourself.
[Django: filtering expected content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408715/django-filtering-expected-content-type)